# Not able to install Apache Tomcat6 to eclipse 3.5 on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: eclipse, apache, ubuntu, tomcat6

I am using Ubuntu 10.10, using eclipse 3.5. I am developing a web application which needs apache tomcat6. I have downloaded and installed tomcat6.0 using synaptic manager, but eclipse 3.5 says "The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar." though i have browsed through till the installation dir /usr/share/tomcat6.

Please suggest me the solution to install the apache tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I am using Ubuntu 10.04, and Eclipse 3.5. I was following this tutorial:

```
 http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html
```

I tried to create an apache tomcat6 server using

```
 Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments
```

but got your error messages. Others had proposed fixes involving changing permissions

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447289/problem-creating-a-tomcat-6-server-
```

in-eclipse-form-ubuntu

That concerned me. I avoided the permission changes and solved it by doing this stuff.

**First:** I had installed tomcat6 using ubuntu 10.04 software center. I removed it then installed tomcat6 from a direct download from apache's site

```
 http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi.
```

I put it into /home/myname/apache-tomcat-6.0.33.

It made it through Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments just fine.

**Second**: then doing this:

```
 Windows -> Show View -> Servers -> Servers
```

would not list anything at all in the Server window it opened up.
After a long time, by chance I right clicked in the Server window which allowed me to do
New -> server
and select the tomcat6 server

That lists it in the server window, then you can start and stop it through that window.

**Third:** I also added these lines to the end of /etc/bash.bashrc but I'm not sure whether that was needed.  I haven't tried to find out for sure.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/"

CATALINA_HOME="/home/chuck/apache-tomcat-6.0.33"

export JAVA_HOME

export CATALINA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

export PATH
```

Comment: @chucko - The thanks are really to you! I just fixed some formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Eclipse assumes the Tomcat configuration directory resides in the same location with the binary directory.
Try this:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat6
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat6/conf conf
```

This should fix it by creating a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about eclipse 3.5, but in older releases you should configure the path of Tomcat inside Eclipse.

Open the preferences dialog by selecting Window > Preferences, select Tomcat from the left tree menu, and select the correct directories there.